# How to implement a service which run on every x second in xamarin ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to implement a service which check my device is connected to TCP or not at every some seconds in Xamarin iOS, I want to implement these in native code.

Comment: Does my answer work ?

Comment: No it's not worked

Comment: What means of not worked  ? The timer didn't work each x seconds ? Or it never been invoked at all .

Answer (score 2):

In Xamarin.iOS you could use **NSTimer**

```
NSTimer _timer;
```

```
 _timer = NSTimer.CreateRepeatingScheduledTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), (timer) =>
          {
                this.InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    //Your code  here
                });
           }
);
```

To Start the Timer

```
_timer.Fire();
```

To End The Timer

```
_timer.Invalidate();
```